# Rails scope with DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, scope

I'm trying to create a set of results to display on a 'Summary' page, but am having trouble filtering for the DateTime in the scope called :can_be_shown_now

When I change the date in the database, my Poster still appears when it should not.

Model

```
class Poster < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :poster_for_summary,    -> { self.where(show_on_summary_page: true) }
  scope :can_be_shown_now,      -> { poster_for_summary.where((:start_time..:end_time).cover?(DateTime.now)) }
  scope :choose_for_summary,    -> { can_be_shown_now.order("RANDOM()").first }
end
```

Application Controller

```
def fallback_poster
  @fallback_poster = Poster.choose_for_summary  if controller_name == 'summary'
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `cover?` method refers to given range, not a query. You should try something like this:

```
scope :can_be_shown_now,  -> { poster_for_summary.where(["`posters`.start_time <= ? AND `posters`.end_time >= ?", t = DateTime.now, t]) }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there something wrong with my third scope then?  Now I'm getting PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

Comment: @bft I don't use Postgres, but it seems to be related to `RANDOM()` function defined within the database. To be sure you should inspect the query dumped when this exception occurs.

Comment: ok, it just didn't like the `` marks, and now my view is rendering. However, `:can_be_shown_now` seems to be filtering out valid results. ie. when I check the console, I'm able to return my test data for `Poster.poster_for_summary`, but not for `Poster.can_be_shown_now`

Comment: What do you mean writing that you're not able to return the test data for `Poster.can_be_shown_now`? Is there an exception or something else? AFAIK it should work.

Comment: In the console: `Poster.poster_for_summary` gives me one result, and `show_on_summary_page: true` and `start_time: "2015-11-11 06:45:00", end_time: "2015-11-28 00:45:00"`. But when I do `Poster.can_be_shown_now` I get `SELECT "posters".* FROM "posters"  WHERE "posters"."show_on_summary_page" = 't' AND (posters.start_time >= '2015-11-21 11:34:08.536116' AND posters.end_time <= '2015-11-21 11:34:08.536116')
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> `

Comment: I edited the answer: I understand, that current date and time should be between `start_time` and the `end_time`?